# What is the right/preferred way to make a "Edit Detail" component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a page whose 'Data Model' is a collection, for example, an array of people. They are packed into React Components and tiled on the page. Essentially it's like:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { people: /* some data */ };
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.people.map((person) =>
                    <People data={person}></People>)}
            </div>);
    }
}
```

Now I want to attach an edit section for each entry in `<People>` component, which allows the user to update the name, age ... all kinds of information for a specific entry.

Since React does not support mutating props inside components, I searched and found that adding callbacks as props can solve the problem of passing data to parent. But since there are many fields to update, there would be many callbacks such as `onNameChanged`, `onEmailChanged`... which could be very ugly (also more and more verbose as the number of fields keeps growing).

So what is the right way for it?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly? **The best way is Flux** (back to that in a minute).

If you start to get into the process of passing data down the tree in the form of props, then passing it back up to be edited using callbacks, then you're breaking the unidirectional data flow that React is built around.

However, not all projects need to be written to ideal standards and it is possible to build this without Flux (and sometimes it might even be the right solution).

### Without Flux

You can implement this without the need for a mass of callbacks, by passing down a single `edit` function as a prop. This function should take an `id` and a new person object, then update the state inside the parent component whenever it runs. Here's an example.

```
editPerson(id, editedPerson) {
  const people = this.state.people;
  const newFragment = { [id]: editedPerson };

  // create a new list of people, with the updated person in
  this.setState({
    people: Object.assign([], people, newFragment)
  });
},
render() {
  // ...
  {this.state.people.map((person, index) => {
    const edit = this.editPerson.bind(this, index);

    return (
      <People data={person} edit={edit}></People>
    );
  })}
  // ...
}
```

Then inside your person component, any time you make a change to the person, simply pass the person back up to the parent state with the callback.

However, if you visualize the flow of data through your application, you've now created a cycle that looks something like this.

```
 App
  ^
  |
  v
Person
```

It's no longer trivial to work out where the data in app came from (it is still quite simple in such a small app, but obviously the bigger it gets the harder it is to tell.

### With Flux

In the beginning, Facebook developers wrote React applications with unidirectional data flows and they saw that it was good. However, a need arose for data to go up the tree, which resulted in a crisis. How shall our data flow be unidirectional and still return to the top of the tree? And on the seventh day, they created Flux(1) and saw that it was very good.

Flux allows you to describe your changes as actions and pass them out of your components, to stores (self contained state boxes) which understand how to manipulate their state based on the action. Then the store tells all the components that care about it that something has changed, at which point the components can fetch new data to render.

You regain your unidirectional data flow, with an architecture that looks like this.

```
 App <---- [Stores]
  |            ^
  v            |
Person --> Dispatcher
```

#### Stores

Rather than keeping your state in your `<App />` component, you would probably want to create a People store to keep track of your list of people.

Maybe it would look something like this.

```
// stores/people-store.js
const people = [];

export function getPeople() {
  return people;
}
function editPerson(id, person) {
  // ...
}
function addPerson(person) {
  // ...
}
function removePerson(id) {
  // ...
}
```

Now, we could export these functions and let our components call them directly, but that's bad because it means that our components have to have knowledge of the design of the store and we want to keep them as dumb as possible.

#### Actions

Instead, our components create simple, serializable actions that our stores can understand. Here are some examples:

```
// remove person with id 53
{ type: 'PEOPLE_REMOVE', payload: 53 }

// create a new person called John Foo
{ type: 'PEOPLE_ADD', payload: { name: 'John Foo' } }

// edit person 13
{
  type: 'PEOPLE_EDIT',
  payload: {
    id: 13,
    person: { name: 'Unlucky Bill' }
  }
}
```

These actions don't have to have these specific keys, they don't even have to be objects either, this is just the convention from [Flux Standard Actions](https://github.com/acdlite/flux-standard-action).

#### Dispatcher

Now, we have tell our store how to deal with these actions when they arrive.

```
 // stores/people-store.js
 // ...
 dispatcher.register(function(action) {
   switch(action.type) {
     case 'PEOPLE_REMOVE':
       removePerson(action.payload);
     case 'PEOPLE_ADD':
       addPerson(action.payload);
     case 'PEOPLE_EDIT':
       editPerson(action.payload.id, action.payload.person);
   }
 });
```

Phew. Lot of work so far, nearly there.

Now we can start to dispatch these actions from our components.

```
 // components/people.js
 // ...
 onEdit(editedPerson) {
   dispatcher.dispatch({
     type: 'PEOPLE_EDIT',
     payload: {
       id: this.props.id,
       person: editedPerson
     }
   });
 }
 onRemove() {
   dispatcher.dispatch({
     type: 'PEOPLE_REMOVE',
     payload: this.props.id
   });
 }
 // ...
```

When you edit the person, call the `this.onEdit` method and it will dispatch the appropriate action to your stores. Same goes for removing a person. Normally you'd move this stuff into action creators, but that's a topic for another time.

Ok, finally getting somewhere! Now our components can create actions that update the data in our stores. How do we get that data back into our components?

Initially, it's very simple. We can require the store in our top level component and simply ask for the data.

```
// components/app.js
import { getPeople } from './stores/people-store';
// ...
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { people: getPeople() };
}
```

We can pass this data down in exactly the same way, but what happens when the data changes?

The official stance from Flux is basically "Not our problem". [Their examples](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#content) use Node's Event Emitter class to allow stores to accept callback functions that are called when the store updates.

This allows you to write code that looks something like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  peopleStore.addListener(this.peopleUpdated);
},
componentWillUnmount() {
  peopleStore.removeListener(this.peopleUpdated);
},
peopleUpdated() {
  this.setState({ people: getPeople() });
}
```

Really, the ball is in your court on this one. There are many other strategies for getting the data back into your program. [Reflux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs) creates the listen method for you automatically, [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux) allows you to declaratively specify which components receive which parts of the store as props, then it handles the updating. Spend enough time with Flux and you'll find a preference.

Now, you're probably thinking, blimey — this seems like a lot of effort to go to just to add edit functionality to a component; and you're right, it is!

**For small applications, you probably don't need Flux.**

Sure there are lots of benefits, but the additional complexity just isn't always warranted. As your application grows, you'll find that if you've fluxed it up, it will be much easier to manage, maintain and debug.

The trick is to know when it's appropriate to use the Flux architecture and hopefully when the time comes, this overly long, rambling answer will have cleared things up for you.

---

1. This isn't actually true.